# Converting my MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have no record in table. I got this error when i Converting my MyISAM to InnoDB

SQL query: Edit

```
ALTER TABLE `vocabulary` ENGINE = InnoDB
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#1214` - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

### Table structure for table `vocabulary`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vocabulary` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usr` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `word` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `meaning` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `synonym` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `Date` char(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `usr` (`usr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: The error message is saying that your table has at least one `FULLTEXT` index, which InnoDB does not support. I 'm not sure how it could be made more clear.

Comment: @Jon: Reading is boring, GIMME SOME CODES

Comment: Agree with Jon. Probably that was the reason that this table was created on MyISAM in first place.

Comment: Please check Table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MySQL only MyISAM storage engine supports full text indexes

Innodb will not support full text indexes

so in order to convert the table use

```
  alter table vocabulary drop key usr;

  alter table vocabulary engine=innodb;
```